# How to use CASE and IN inside where statement when comparing a variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, case

I don't want to use dynamic SQL so I'm trying different ways to alter my where statement.

Inside my WHERE statement, there is a row:

```
AND c.nregion = pnregion
```

`pnregion` is a number of Russian region. This statement helps my cursor to work a lot faster since Oracle doesn't have to look through the full table.

Problem is that if `pnregion` is equal to 47 or 78 then this row should look like this

```
AND c.nregion in (47, 78)
```

How to do it? Should I use CASE somehow or is there something I could do outside my cursor?

Comment: If your problem is using `IN` when it's only one region code needed without changing the SQL query, you can use a placeholder (e.g. to get only region code 16, you can use `c.nregion IN (16, -12345)` - as far as I know, there is no negative Russian regional codes).

Comment: `IN (<single value>)` does work like `= <single value>`, so you can just use `IN` and don't need to handle the case for when it's only a single value in a special way. If it is that you're looking for...

Comment: @trolley813 it works, but looks bad
`AND    c.nregion IN (pnregion, (CASE pnregion WHEN 47 THEN 78 WHEN 78 THEN 47 ELSE - 1 END))`

Comment: @sticky bit Thank you, but in this case pnregion must be a varchar variable to handle values like `47, 78`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) function to add another option per codes 47/78:

```
AND (c.nregion  = pnregion OR c.nregion = decode(pnregion, 47, 78, 78, 47))
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good! Will it work better and faster than 
`AND c.nregion IN (pnregion, (CASE pnregion WHEN 47 THEN 78 WHEN 78 THEN 47 ELSE - 1 END))` (it is a @trolley813 suggestion)

Comment: More code style preference, Not so much difference, see https://community.oracle.com/thread/1112467

Comment: Don't use `0` if a value does not exist as `c.nregion = 0` could possibly be true if someone updates the business logic to make `0` a valid value without understanding the implications. Instead, use `NULL` as `c.nregion = NULL` will never be true.

Comment: @MT0 Updated answer, removed default value because NULL is the default for decode

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
WHERE ( c.nregion = pnregion
      OR (   pnregion  IN ( 47, 78 )
         AND c.nregion IN ( 47, 78 )
         )
      )
```

This is easily extensible if you want more than 2 values as the values can be added to both `IN` filters.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question, it is a *varying elements in IN list* that bothers you. In other words, you can't put comma-separated values into an IN list, unless you

- switch to dynamic SQL (which is what you don't want)
- separate those values into rows

Here's an example, based on Scott's schema; I hope you'll understand it.

This is what you currently have:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (pnregion in varchar2)
  2  is
  3    cursor c1 is select empno, ename from emp
  4      where deptno in pnregion;
  5  begin
  6    for cr in c1 loop
  7      dbms_output.put_line(cr.ename);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL> -- This is OK
SQL> exec p_test('10');
CLARK
KING
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> -- This is not OK
SQL> exec p_test('10, 20');
BEGIN p_test('10, 20'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_TEST", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

Now, split comma-separated values to rows and watch it work:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (pnregion in varchar2)
  2  is
  3    cursor c1 is select empno, ename from emp
  4      where deptno in (select regexp_substr(pnregion, '[^,]+', 1, level)
  5                       from dual
  6                       connect by level <= regexp_count(pnregion, ',') + 1
  7                      );
  8  begin
  9    for cr in c1 loop
 10      dbms_output.put_line(cr.ename);
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL> -- This is OK
SQL> exec p_test('10');
CLARK
KING
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> -- This is also OK now
SQL> exec p_test('10, 20');
SMITH
JONES
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
ADAMS
FORD
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> -- Or even some more values:
SQL> exec p_test('10, 20,30');
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD
JONES
MARTIN
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
TURNER
ADAMS
JAMES
FORD
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```